# Ensure that AMQP exchange exists before publishing a message to it

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

## Problem

A Java application uses RabbitMQ and client library `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client` to connect to it. The application declares an AMQP exchange during initialization and periodically publishes messages to it.

**If that exchange gets removed for some reason the application cannot publish messages to it and the AMQP channel gets automatically closed by the library**. So any subsequent publishes (even after the exchange is re-created) fail with such exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'logs' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:195)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:296)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:648)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:631)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:622)
```

How can I guarantee that the exchange does exist before publish? I see the following options.

## Possible solutions

### 1. Try to re-declare exchange before each publish explicitly

Thanks to the fact that `exchangeDeclare` is idempotent and has no effect if the exchange is already in place I could explicitly declare the exchange before any publish:

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", false, true, null);
channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, message);
```

The issue with this code is that it looks stupid because most of the time the exchange is in place and the declaration is just redundant.

Also I'm still be in trouble if the exchange is deleted exactly between declaration and publish.

### 2. Verify that exchange does exist via `exchangeDeclarePassive`

I could use `exchangeDeclarePassive` to check that the exchange exists before publish but the following obvious method doesn't work:

```
private static void ensureExchangeExists(Channel channel) throws IOException {
    try {
        channel.exchangeDeclarePassive(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", false, true, null);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the exchange is missing, `exchangeDeclarePassive` throws the exception and the channel is closed automatically by the library. So the code in catch block cannot declare the exchange (because it tries to perform an operation on the closed channel).

So I can no longer use single AMQP channel and have to manage them in some way.

Also I'm still in trouble if the exchange is removed between declaration and publish.

### 3. Catch exception upon publish

You cannot just wrap call channel.basicPublish with a try/catch block because if the exchange is missing then no exception is thrown. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528788/15647) explains what actually happens in this situation.

But you can register a `ShutdownListener` that is able to detect when a channel is closed, investigate the reason (via `cause.isInitiatedByApplication()`/`cause.getReason()`) and do the necessary action.

## Question

The question is what is the best way to ensure that AMQP exchange exists before publishing a message to it and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I chose option #3 (Catch exception upon publish) in combination with [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) that are necessary to track the messages that were not successfully published.

Answer (score 3):

IME, option #1 is the close to the better option.

What I've found works best, is to have the code for a given publisher encapsulated in a way that lets me declare / re-declare the queue the first time I create the object instance. Then I can re-use the same object instance to publish messages without having to re-declare the exchange again.

If I create a new instance of the object, it will re-declare the exchange. But re-using the same instance prevents that from happening.

This strategy has worked well for me.

the other option is to pre-define and pre-declare your exchanges, queues and bindings at the app startup. that way you don't have to worry about it anymore. the downside here, is you have pre-determine all exchanges, queues and bindings... which works in some apps but not in others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Derrick. The problem however is that the exchange is removed by some external party when application is running. So it may disappear at any time from the application perspective. And hence neither eager nor lazy initialization works.

Comment: in that case, you should go with option #1 and re-declare the exchange before sending any message. note that this will incur massive performance penalties... you should work with the team that runs the other system to fix the root of the problem, but re-declare before send should be sufficient for now

Comment: well, no. i take that back. you should probably use a combination of option #1 and option #3, because of the possibility of the exchange being deleted before the publish, as you noted in the original post. you should treat the missing exchange as a known failure condition, and provide a backup solution to re-try the message later, after the exchange has been recreated. this is often done with a log file or even in-memory list of messages to retry, from the publisher side of things