# ConfirmListener.handleNack is not invoked when exchange is missing

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

In my application I need to determine whether a message is successfully published into AMQP exchange or some error happens. It seems like [Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) were invented to address this issue so I started experimenting with them.

For my Java application I used `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.5.4` and I chose a very simple scenario when the exchange (where I try to publish) is missing. I expected that `ConfirmListener.handleNack` is going to be invoked in such case.

Here's my Java code:

```
package wheleph.rabbitmq_tutorial.confirmed_publishes;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConfirmListener;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ConfirmedPublisher {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfirmedPublisher.class);

    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "confirmed.publishes";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.confirmSelect();
        channel.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
            public void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
                logger.debug(String.format("Received ack for %d (multiple %b)", deliveryTag, multiple));
            }

            public void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple) throws IOException {
                logger.debug(String.format("Received nack for %d (multiple %b)", deliveryTag, multiple));
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String message = "Hello world" + channel.getNextPublishSeqNo();
            channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", null, message.getBytes());
            logger.info(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

However it's not the case. Log shows that no callback is executed:

```
17:49:34,988 [main] ConfirmedPublisher -  [x] Sent 'Hello world1'
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'confirmed.publishes' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:195)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:309)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:657)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:640)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:631)
    at wheleph.rabbitmq_tutorial.confirmed_publishes.ConfirmedPublisher.main(ConfirmedPublisher.java:38)
```

What's interesting is that pubilsher confirms work as expected when I try to use library for NodeJS [amqp-coffee](https://github.com/dropbox/amqp-coffee) (0.1.24).

Here's my NodeJS code:

```
var AMQP = require('amqp-coffee');

var connection = new AMQP({host: 'localhost'});
connection.setMaxListeners(0);

console.log('Connection started')

connection.publish('node.confirm.publish', '', 'some message', {deliveryMode: 2, confirm: true}, function(err) {
     if (err && err.error && err.error.replyCode === 404) {
         console.log('Got 404 error')
     } else if (err) {
         console.log('Got some error')
     } else {
         console.log('Message successfully published')
     }
  })
```

Here's the output that indicates that the callback is invoked with proper argument:

```
Connection started
Got 404 error
```

Am I using `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client` incorrectly or there's some inconsistency in that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my assumption was not correct and `ConfirmListener.handleNack` should not be invoked in this case.

Here's a relevant portion of AMQP messages for the scenario described in the question observed for [amqp-coffee](https://github.com/dropbox/amqp-coffee) library:

```
ch#1 -> {#method<channel.open>(out-of-band=), null, ""}
ch#1 <- {#method<channel.open-ok>(channel-id=), null, ""}
ch#1 -> {#method<confirm.select>(nowait=false), null, ""}
ch#1 <- {#method<confirm.select-ok>(), null, ""}
ch#1 -> {#method<basic.publish>(ticket=0, exchange=node.confirm.publish, routing-key=, mandatory=false, immediate=false), #contentHeader<basic>(content-type=string/utf8, content-encoding=null, headers=null, delivery-mode=2, priority=null, correlation-id=null, reply-to=null, expiration=null, message-id=null, timestamp=null, type=null, user-id=null, app-id=null, cluster-id=null), "some message"}
ch#1 <- {#method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'node.confirm.publish' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40), null, ""}
ch#2 -> {#method<channel.open>(out-of-band=), null, ""}
ch#2 <- {#method<channel.open-ok>(channel-id=), null, ""}
ch#2 -> {#method<confirm.select>(nowait=false), null, ""}
ch#2 <- {#method<confirm.select-ok>(), null, ""}
```

You can see that:

1. After unsuccessful publish the channel is closed by broker using `channel.close` that includes the reason.
2. `basic.nack` is not sent.
3. The library automatically opens another channel for subsequent operations.

This behaviour can be implemented in Java using `ShutdownListener`:

```
package wheleph.rabbitmq_tutorial.confirmed_publishes;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownListener;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ConfirmedPublisher {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfirmedPublisher.class);
    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "confirmed.publishes";

    // Beware that proper synchronization of channel is needed because current approach may lead to race conditions
    private volatile static Channel channel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);

        final Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (channel == null) {
                createChannel(connection);
            }
            String message = "Hello world" + i;
            channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "", null, message.getBytes());
            logger.info(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    private static void createChannel(final Connection connection) throws IOException {
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.confirmSelect(); // This in fact is not necessary
        channel.addShutdownListener(new ShutdownListener() {
            public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
                // Beware that proper synchronization is needed here
                logger.debug("Handling channel shutdown...", cause);
                if (cause.isInitiatedByApplication()) {
                    logger.debug("Shutdown is initiated by application. Ignoring it.");
                } else {
                    logger.error("Shutdown is NOT initiated by application. Resetting the channel.");
                    /* We cannot re-initialize channel here directly because ShutdownListener callbacks run in the connection's thread,
                       so the call to createChannel causes a deadlock since it blocks waiting for a response (whilst the connection's thread
                       is stuck executing the listener). */
                    channel = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There're few caveats:

1. Publisher confirms are not necessary in this case because we don't use `ConfirmListener` or any other functionality specific to that approach. However publisher confirms would be useful if we wanted to track which messages were successfully send and which not.
2. If we launch `ConfirmedPublisher` and after some time create the missing exchange, all following messages will be successfully published. However all the previous failed messages are lost.
3. Additional synchronization is needed.